Childrens book about each food group being a shelf pyramid in child's tummy and saying full of healthy food yet space for the top for dessert
I'm looking for the title of a childrens book about a boy who thinks his stomach is shelves each showing a food category.  The picture shows his shelf full of health foods so he doesn't want any more healthy food but his dessert shelf is empty and he wants dessert.  I believe each food category was in the pyramid shape with veggies/ fruits on the bottom and desserts on the top.  I read this to my children in the mid 90s but probable is from published before that time.

What country was this in? If it was the US, the book might be connected to the USDA Food Pyramid, which was introduced in 1992.

This sounds like Lionel at Large, by Stephen Krensky, illustrated by Susanna Natti, published in 1986 in the "Dial easy-to-read" series.

The first chapter is titled "Vegetables." Lionel's mother is trying to get him to eat his green beans.

"There's no room for them," said Lionel.
"You had room for your hamburger," said Mother. She always ate everything too.
"That was different," said Lionel.
"Oh?" said Mother.
Lionel looked down at his stomach. "I have shelves in here," he explained. "They hold the food I eat."
Lionel felt one rib. "Here is my hamburger shelf," he said.
Lionel felt another rib. "Here is my bread shelf," he said.
"What about your vegetable shelf?" asked Father.
Lionel felt both sides. "I don't have one," he said.



"Time for dessert," said Mother.
"Hooray!" said Lionel.
"Too bad you can't have any," said Father.
"What do you mean?" Lionel asked.



"I've read a lot about these shelves," said Father. "The books say that if you have no vegetable shelf, you have no dessert shelf either."
...
Lionel felt his ribs again. "Wait!" he shouted. "I think I found my vegetable shelf. It was hidden under the bread shelf."


The book is available to borrow at the Internet Archive.
